# How do I get regex to capture one-letter words and multiple letter words?

Tags: python, regex

The following regex pattern does *almost* everything I need it to do, including catching contractions:

```
re_pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+\\'?[a-zA-Z]+"
```

However, if I enter the following code:

```
sent = "I can't understand what I'm doing wrong or if I made a mistake."

re.findall(re_pattern, sent)
```

It doesn't pick up one-letter words, such as `I` or `a`:

```
["can't", 'understand', 'what', "I'm", 'doing', 'wrong', 'or', 'if', 'made', 'mistake']
```

Comment: Why _would_ it capture single-letter words? Only the `'` is optional, so it requires at least one letter followed by at least one letter, optionally with a `'` in-between.

Comment: Try changing last + (i.e. 1 or more) to * (0 or more) i.e. `re_pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+\\'?[a-zA-Z]*"`

Comment: Ah, just goes to show what a noob I am at this. Thanks friends :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to match at least 2 character words, as the second + also requires at least one match, with an optional `'` in between.
Changing it to an optional * will do it

```py
>>> re_pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+\\'?[a-zA-Z]*"
>>> re.findall(re_pattern, sent)
['I', "can't", 'understand', 'what', "I'm", 'doing', 'wrong', 'or', 'if', 'I', 'made', 'a', 'mistake']
```

Comment: Note that this will also match words that end with an apostrophe, like `students'` (as in "the students' backpacks"), which may or may not be desired.

Comment: What if, for the purpose of pulling sentences, I wanted to retain the fullstop as well?

Comment: ...and, as per your example, not include that last `'`

Comment: If you do not want the abostrophe. See Wiktor's answer for that `(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?\b` needs characters behind it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```py
re_pattern = r"[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x70VBA/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YCdq7Y):

```py
import re
re_pattern = r"[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?"
sent = "I can't understand what I'm doing wrong or if I made a mistake."
print( re.findall(re_pattern, sent) )
# => ['I', "can't", 'understand', 'what', "I'm", 'doing', 'wrong', 'or', 'if', 'I', 'made', 'a', 'mistake']
```

**Note**: If you needn't extract letter sequences glued to `_` or digits, use word boundaries:

```py
re_pattern = r"\b[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?\b"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x70VBA/2). And if you plan to match any Unicode words:

```py
re_pattern = r"\b[^\W\d_]+(?:'[^\W\d_]+)?\b"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x70VBA/3).

Ah, and if you want to also match digits and underscores as part of "words", just use

```py
re_pattern = r"\w+(?:'\w+)*"
```

The `*` after `(?:'\w+)` allows matching words like `rock'n'roll`.

Comment: Also nailed it! Thanks so much good sir!